# Reason to use Spring Dependency Injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, dependencies

I'm currently studying Spring and suddenly, I've got curious about DI

And my question is **What're the main reasons to use DI?**

Sorry for Duplicate Question..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638919/how-to-explain-dependency-injection-to-a-5-year-old

Comment: Duplicate of: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500637/understanding-the-need-for-a-di-framework), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061717/what-exactly-is-spring-for), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131975/what-are-the-benefits-of-dependency-injection-containers) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DI is automated, configurable way of instantiating graph of objects. From *Spring in Action, Craig Walls, Ryan Breidenbach*:

> Any nontrivial application is made up of two or more classes that
> collaborate with each other to perform some business logic.
> Traditionally, each object is responsible for obtaining its own
> references to the objects it collaborates with (its dependencies).
> When applying DI, the objects are given their dependencies at creation
> time by some external entity that coordinates each object in the
> system. In other words, dependencies are injected into objects.

You may read answers on question :"[What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130794/617996)". That way you'll get clearer picture, what are the main reasons to use it.

And maybe take a look at that great [article](http://codefornothing.wordpress.com/2007/11/11/why-use-dependency-injection/).