# Different between Autowired Services and Objects Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I was wondering what is the difference between creating a new class and injecting it with the @Autowired annotation and creating a class and take the object of this class and using its methods. Is there any techical reason(i.e. faster access etc)?

Service case:

```
 @Service
 public class AuthorService implements AuthorServiceInterface {


   //some methods
 }
```

Simple Class case:

```
 public class AuthorService implements AuthorServiceInterface {


   //some methods
 }
```

If i want to call the first one in another class i have to write:

```
public Class myclass{

    @Autowired
    AuthorService authorservice;


}
```

In the second case i have to write:

```
public Class myclass{


    AuthorService authorservice = new AuthorService():

}
```

Whats the difference between these two cases?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by two code snippets?

Comment: @JB Nizet I update my answer.

Comment: @Nick Robertson because you want to take advantage of spring `dependency injection` to create objects for you. It certainly looks more nicely with `@Autowired`. More loosely coupled and high cohesive code.

Comment: please see this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131975/what-are-the-benefits-of-dependency-injection-containers and red 20 mins ago
JB Nizets answer pretty much sums it.sorry I have to leave don't have time to write xamples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first snippet uses dependency injection, and the second doesn't. Dependency injection allows

- decoupling MyClass from the concrete implementation of AuthorService which would allow switching implementations depending on the environment for example
- using a singleton (or session-scoped or request-scope) AuthorService rather than reinstantiating one each time
- injecting a mock AuthorService implementation when unit-testing MayClass
- injecting a proxy around the concrete AuthorService instance, which could

  - verify authorizations
  - start a transaction before each method call and commit/rollback it after the method call
  - log the method calls
  - measure the time taken by methods and compute statistics
  - invoke an AuthorService on another machine, using RMI or HttpInvoker
  - ...

Note that you should autowire AuthorServiceInterface, and not AuthorService, in MyClass.

Comment: I understand your answer.That i want to ask now,if i use the first approach the process will become faster?

Comment: @Nick Robertson Short answer probably. But that is micro optimization and plus if the project becomes large enough it may be hectic to maintain it.

Comment: @ant what do you mean when you say "it may be hectic to maintain it"?

Comment: It could become faster. But performance is not the reson why you use dependency injection. Anyway, this is not where time is specnt in a typical application. Concentrate on IO, databse queries, interprocess calls, complex algorithms.